# Android: One font, multiple styles, multiple files - how do I combine them to one?

Tags: android, xml, fonts, styles

I have got one font and from it different ttf files:

```
regular.ttf
bold.ttf
italic.ttf
bold_italic.ttf
light.ttf
```

Is it possible to combine them to one in for example the `styles.xml` file? So that I, when I set a bold span, really have the text shown in bold (from bold.ttf)?

Comment: Have you refereed this ? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml

Comment: yeah, i have read this, but I cannot get my font bold this way?